# What is the probability that the 3 remaining cards of the suit are in one player's hand?

Tags: probability

A standard pack of 52 cards with 4 suits (each having 13 denominations) is well shuffled and dealt out to 4 players (N, S, E and W).

They each receive 13 cards.

If N and S have exactly 10 cards of a specified suit between them.

What is the probability that the 3 remaining cards of the suit are in one player's hand (either E or W)? Can you please just help me understand how to solve this conditional probability question?

Comment: [Bridge probabilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_probabilities). [More](http://www.bridgehands.com/P/Probability_of_Card_Distribution.htm), and [even more](http://www.durangobill.com/BrSplitStats.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you condition, you get that you have 26 cards left and 3 of them are of the particular suit. There are $26 \choose 13$ ways of assigning these remaining 26 cards among E and W (because once you assign 13 cards to E, the remaining 13 cards automatically go to W. You get that one player has all 3 cards if either E has 3 or E has 0. The number of ways E could have all 3 is $23 \choose 10$. The number of ways E could have 0 is $23 \choose 13$ which is also $23 \choose 10$. So $2 {23 \choose 10}/{26 \choose 13}$ is the answer.

Answer (score 3):

It can be thought of as drawing $3$ distinct numbers out of the set $\{1,\dots,26\}$ and to find the probability that the numbers all three belong to set $\{1,\dots,13\}$ or to set $\{14,\dots,26\}$.

This results in $2\times\frac{13}{26}\times\frac{12}{25}\times\frac{11}{24}=\frac{11}{50}$

Actually you can start by 'reserving' number $1$ for the first number and then find the probability that the others will belong to set $\{2,\dots,13\}$.

This results is $\frac{12}{25}\times\frac{11}{24}=\frac{11}{50}$

---

Background thinking:

Think of placing the $26$ cards (that contain $3$ cards of the specified suit) randomly in a row. The first $13$ cards in this row are for East and the last are for West. There is no objection at all against *starting* this ordering with the $3$ specials.

Answer (score 0):

[Click to see my answer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlXWg.png)

See the picture. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.